# Does PerformImmediateLogin throw a custom exception? If so, what is the type?

Tags: vaultsharp

When calling we'd like to be able to catch any exceptions in a try catch and hand over to our handler.

```
IVaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient(vaultClientSettings);
try {
    vaultClient.V1.Auth.PerformImmediateLogin();
} catch ( Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general, all VaultSharp APIs tend to throw this custom exception.

`VaultApiException`

See here for the fields.

https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/blob/master/src/VaultSharp/Core/VaultApiException.cs

However, the `PerformImmediateLogin` can also throw the `Exception` type when the HTTP login call to Vault does succeed but the response has an empty AuthInfo object (thus not giving back a vault token). This may or may not happen in real life, but this is the only case where `Exception` is thrown. Otherwise, you can always expect VaultSharp to throw the `VaultApiException` type.